# Signing into Github Copilot for Business from PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, github-copilot

We just got a github copilot for business license. I've done the following within my PyCharm IDE:

1. Installed copilot via plugins and restarted.
2. Connected to our enterprise account via:

   - Version control -> Github
   - Log in to Github Enterprise
   - Generated a token with repo, gist, and read:org scopes enabled

Now I want to sign in with Copilot. But when I click "sign in to github", it still wants me to sign in with a password at https://github.com/login/device (not how you sign in with an enterprise account). If I try manually redirecting to https://github.mycompany.com/login/device and entering the code there, I get "Uh oh, we couldn't find anything".

I'm surprised this isn't better documented but I can't find any relevant pages. Input appreciated.

Comment: Was there any solution for this? I still cant find any relevant docs.

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj - Yes, just posted.

Answer (score 1):

These were the steps that worked for me:

1. Signed into our enterprise organization with single sign on [https://github.com/enterprises/{organization}](https://github.com/enterprises/%7Borganization%7D) (This was the important missing step)
2. Then Version Control -> Log in via GitHub (not Github Enterprise). You're taken to a Jetbrains page to auth.
3. Then Tools -> Github copilot -> Login. Here you enter a device code, click on "Copy and Open", and then authorize the GitHub CoPilot plugin in the browser.